# Осуществить ajax-запрос повторяющихся форм в цикле

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня циклом выводится список номеров в отеле. Напротив каждого номера мне надо сделать небольшую форму с select и кнопкой. При нажатии на кнопку должно выводиться значение option из select.
Ajax я реализовал, но выводится значение только у первого элемента, т.к. jQuery останавливается на первом найденном. Я вижу причину ошибки. Нужна помощь - как сконфигурировать так, чтобы каждая форма обрабатывалась отдельно и выводила своё значение? Я в js  не силён просто.
Эта форма, которая выводится циклом в каждом номере:

```
    <form method="POST" id = "formx" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID();  ?>"  action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">

    <p>
        Кол-во бронируемых номеров:
        <select id="room_num_search" class="room_num_search" name="room_num_search">
            <?php for($i=1; $i <= $show; $i++): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;  ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php endfor;  ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Тут будет выведен результат

Это мой Ajax:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call() {
        var msg   = jQuery("#formx").serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            // Метод передачи
            type: 'POST',
            // Файл которому передаем запрос и получаем ответ
            url: 'path/to/ajax.php'   ?>',
            // Кеширование
            cache: false,
            // Верямя ожидания ответа, в мили секундах 1000 мс = 1 сек
            timeout:3000,
            data: msg,
            // Функция сработает при успешном получении данных
            success: function(data) {
                // Отображаем данные в форме
                jQuery("#results").html(data);
            },
            // Функция срабатывает в период ожидания данных
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                jQuery("#results").html('<p>Ожидание данных...</p>');
            },
            // Тип данных
            dataType:"html",
            // Функция сработает в случае ошибки
            error:  function(data){
                jQuery("#results").html('<p>Возникла неизвестная ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте чуть позже...</p>');
            },
        });
    };
</script>
```

Сам обработчик ajax.php:

```
    <?php
foreach ($_POST as $value){
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: `jQuery("formx")` - нет у вас в html такой формы.. `url: 'path/to/ajax.php'   ?>',` - тут "?>';" - лишнее.. Так-то вы форму у функцию передавайте -> `... onsubmit="call(this)" ... function call(form) {...` и потом в скрипте -> `var msg   = $(form).serialize();`

Comment: @InDevX да, работает, но как ещё сделать так, чтобы результаты выводились в элемент jQuery('#result'), который у каждого номера отеля свой? Пока выводится в первый #result

Comment: А где он у формы? Не вижу у ваc в коде ничего с id results. Добавьте код с ним в тему

Comment: @InDevX , извиняюсь, пропустил при копировании, сейчас вставил

Comment: По правилам CSS и JS аттрибут `ID` должен быть уникальным. jQuery в данном случае находит первый элемент с заданным `ID` и присваивает ему значение. Поэтому всё работает правильно. Если же хотите, чтобы данные менялись для конкретного элемента, то задайте ему уникальный аттрибут `ID`, например: `id="room_num_search<?= get_the_ID();?>"`

Comment: @Kosmos , да, я так, в принципе, и задавал, чтобы id были уникальными, но как в самом js прописать? 
id="result<?= get_the_ID();?>"
Как осуществить поиск именно этого id через js?

Comment: 1) можно точно так же в цикле забиндить обработчики под все ID. 2) У меня не самый правильный вариант, но я ID выношу в отдельный параметр, типа `data-hotel-id="<?= get_the_ID();?>"` и уже от него отталкиваюсь. Более подробный пример написать не могу, т.к. изначально код в примере указан не полностью.

Comment: @Kosmos вот как я реализовал, опираясь на Ваш совет:
1) Изменил форму: <form method="get" class = "formx" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID();  ?>"  action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call(this)">
2)Изменил место вывода результата: <div class="results" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID();  ?>">Тут будет выведен результат</div>
3)Изменил условие выдачи в ajax-запросе:                 jQuery('.results').each(function(i){
                    if(jQuery(this).data('id') === jQuery(form).data('id')){
                        jQuery(this).html(data);
                    }
                })

Comment: Разным тегам лучше присваивать разные имена аттирбутов `data-`, чтобы не было путаницы.В результате заработало?

Comment: @Kosmos, да, теперь работает. Но теперь я пытаюсь в файле ajax.php подключить к БД и создать в ней запись - сервер почему-то падает с ошибкой 500 . Сам запрос распечатывал - он работает в phpMyAdmin:
global $wpdb;
$room_num_search = $_POST['room_num_search'];
$res = $wpdb->get_results("INSERT INTO `multiple_booking` (`room_num_search`)
        VALUES (`$room_num_search`)");

Comment: @Kosmos , я так и не понял почему выдавалась ошибка, мне кажется, из-за global $wpdb - глобальной переменной для подключения к БД WordPress, сделал по-обычному, средствами php, где всё заработало:
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
$room_num_search = $_POST['room_num_search'];
$query ="INSERT INTO `multiple_booking` (`room_num_search`)
        VALUES ($room_num_search)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

Comment: Так не скажу, нужно смотреть. И писать переменные в БД напрямую ***очень не рекомендую***. См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0